# BJam script accessing Linux username?

Tags: boost, bjam

I have a bjam script:

```
import python ;
lib ttclientlib : : <name>ttclient <search>$(ttclient_dir)/lib <link>static  ;
explicit ttclientlib ;  

project ib
  : requirements
        <location>. 
        <cxxflags>"-std=c++11 -Wno-deprecated -I /home/username/workspace"
;

python-extension _tt_bridge : tt_bridge.cpp ;
```

I would like to replace 'username' with the linux environment variable referring to the user running the bjam script.

How is this achieved?

Comment: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/bbv2/faq.html#bbv2.faq.envar

Comment: @llonesmiz Hi, I did come across that technique, the problem was concatenating the value within the GCC switch string.

Comment: [An example that does something similar to what you want](https://github.com/boostorg/build/blob/develop/src/tools/clang-win.jam#L145) and [the reference docs for `path.join`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/bbv2/reference.html#bbv2.reference.modules.path). You would need something like: `path.join /home $(YOUR_USERNAME_VARIABLE) workspace`.